# Prevent form leave the screen c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a project that i'm working on, and for this project i need to prevent
from the window to leave the bounds of the screen.

I figured out how to do it, but the window is "lagging" or "jumping" and i don't want it to be happen.

my current code:

```
private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Top < 0)
        {
            this.Top = 0;
        }
        if (this.Left < 0)
        {
            this.Left = 0;
        }
        if (this.Left + this.Width > Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size.Width)
        {
            this.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size.Width - this.Width;
        }
        if (this.Top + this.Height > Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size.Height)
        {
            this.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size.Height - this.Height;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The control already moved, you'll need to go lower e.g. onmessaage and cancel the event if the rect is oob.

Comment: This would be very unfriendly to multiple monitor setups.